# Unable to mount O2 HiLink Huawei E3131 Ubunutu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, mount, internet, huawei

When trying to connect to the internet with an Hilink Huawei E3131 I get

```
Unable to mount O2 HiLink
Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/gman/O2 HiLink: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660"  
    -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500"  
     "/dev/sr0" "/media/gman/O2 HiLink"'  
    exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only 
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

I can get it to work in a round about way but I have to delete the wired connection (it shows up as disable networking), then restart my computer and enable networking and plug in device.
This must be done every time I want to connect to the internet.

By the way i am new to linux.

Comment: It appears as if this problem solved itself upon upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Huawei device.  Insert the device.  Close the error window and ignore it.  Open your Google chrome and try to connect to a website.  You may have to try a couple .  Then a page `192.168.1.1` will appear.  That is how you can connect.  Bookmark that page HiLink.  Then click connect.  When connected close the tab.  Open the browser again and surf away.

It is not important if your device shows up as a wired connection.  Don't delete it if you wish to stay connected.